# Expose mongoose models via Node.js REST service

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose

There are following schemas:

```
var Quest = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true }
});

var Attempt = new Schema({
    quest: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Quest' },
    success: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false }
});

var Person = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    attempts: [Attempt]
});
```

We have a list of quests and a list of people. Every time some person attempts to pass a quest, we create an `Attempt` entry.
It would be nice to expose a `Person` via my REST service so, that it would have a list of empty `Attempt`s containing all attached attempts plus one attempt for every `Quest` that wasn't attempted.

I've ended up having something like this:

```
router.get('/people/:id', function(req, res) {
    return PeopleModel.findById(req.params.id, function (err, person) {
        if(!person) {
            ....
        }
        if (!err) {
            return QuestsModel.find(function (err, quests) {
                if (!err) {
                    var result = person.attempts;
                    quests.forEach(function(quest){
                        var attempt = person.attempts.find(attempt=>{attempt.quest == quest._id});
                        if(!attempt)
                        {
                          var newAttempt = {
                                quest: quest,
                                success: false
                          };
                          result.push(newAttempt);
                        }
                        else {
                          result.push(attempt);
                        }
                    });
                    person.attempts = result;
                    return res.send({ status: 'OK', person:person });
                } else {
                   ...
                }
            });
        } else {
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

That doesn't feel right. Is there a common practice for such situations? Maybe some kind of mapping.

Comment: uhmmm, in my opinion it's more a personal preference than "the right way to do".
The Mongoose framework follow the Active Record Pattern so what you are doing is "OK" thinking that you will have a fat controller using Active Record Pattern.
Personally I prefer to have a business layer to aggregate the business workflow, so your controller layer would be "skinny" and your business layer would be "fat".

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does not feel right?

Comment: @inf3rno to expose mongoose models "as they are", with all the inner fields